# Limit Access to Stored Files on a per-user Basis

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, apache

I have a Web App which serves XML files to users. 
Currently I store them in a directory under Apache and the links to them in MySQL, but it does not allow me to limit access to files.

For example, I'd like to only allow access to `/files/test.xml` to some users.

What is the best way to do so?

The Back-End is in node.js(loopback) and the Front-End in Angular.

The Web API has a route `user/:id/files` which returns a JSON with files.

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Test File",
    url: "/files/test.xml"
}
```

This route is protected with a token (only owner can call it). But the file URL isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tool [GitHub](https://github.com/ajakubek/mod_download_token) allows to set tokens with an expiry date on specific files/folders.